# PHP/Laravel looks like we got no XML document when making soapcall

Tags: php, laravel, soap, soapui, soap-client

I am trying to do a soap call and I keep getting the following error:

> looks like we got no XML document

### EDIT error message

[image]

here's an example that works fine in my SOAP UI

[image]

Here's my array that I send to my soapCall:

```
$params = [
    'id' => '0000002721',
    'options' => [
                    'returnAttachments' => 'false',
                    'returnPictures'    => 'false',
                    'returnContract'    => 'false'
                 ]
];
```

Here is the code how I make the soap call

```
try {
    $options = array(
        'ssl' => array(
            'verify_peer' => false,
            'verify_peer_name' => false,
            'allow_self_signed' => true
        )
    );

    $context = stream_context_create($options);

    $soapClient = new SoapClient(__DIR__ . '/Soap.wsdl', [
        'stream_context' => $context,
        'login' => 'login',
        'password' => 'password',
        'trace' => 1,
            'exceptions' => true,
    ]);

    $soapClient->__setLocation('url');

    $this->soapClient = $soapClient;
} catch (\SoapFault $e) {
    var_dump($e); exit;
}

try {
    $result = $this->soapClient->__soapCall('getMaintenanceObject', $params);
} catch (\SoapFault $e) {
    var_dump($e); exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SoapClient can be not very expressive when it comes to displaying the errors, add this:

`var_dump($this->soapClient->__getLastRequestHeaders());`
`var_dump($this->soapClient->__getLastResponseHeaders());`

Comment: unfortunately this does nothing.

Comment: Is it display anything at all? I had issues like this before, if you are having authentication issues or anything similar these will be hidden and you will get empty XMLs like you are having, and the actual response could can only be visualized by using the lines I posted.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the result I get in my browser

Comment: Add the two var_dump lines I posted after `} catch (\SoapFault $e) {` and see if you get some information. The information was not beign dumped cause a SoapFault was being thrown.